# nslookup how to get list of domains in a DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, nslookup

I want to list all domains In a DNS Server.

**More details:**
spouse that `foo.com` is a web hosting company and `ns1.foo.com` is their DNS server. the web sites `foo1.com` to `foo100.com` are hosted by this company and their dns server is set to `ns1.foo.com`.

I'm looking for a query instead of `required_magic_ls` and a response like following:

```
server ns1.foo.com
required_magic_ls

foo1.com
foo2.com
foo3.com
foo4.com
foo5.com
...
foo99.com
foo100.com
```

if there is not such query in `nslookup` and other dns tools, what is the solution to get such list?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not the administrator for the hosting company's nameservers, you can't without their permission. If you're not the administrator for the hosting company's nameserver and you *can* get zone transfers for all available domains, then you need to hire a drifter to kill everyone associated with the company.